# Flutter - How I create PUBG Uc Purchasing App?

Tags: flutter

I want to create an application where user can buy uc from my app and get it directly on their pubg account. How can I do this in flutter?
Is there any API for doing this?
Some Example What I want..

[MidasBuy](https://www.midasbuy.com/coda/pk/buy/pubgm?from=__mds_buy_coda.codashop_pk)

[CodeShop](https://www.codashop.com/pk/pubg-mobile-uc-redeem-code)

I Found this API. Can I do it with this API?

[Api](https://documentation.pubg.com/en/introduction.html)

Answer (score 0):

```json
{ "create Transaction Request": { "merchant Authentication": { "name": "9bSaKC66uHg", "transaction Key": "8xszx7B7674QxHqe" }, "ref Id": "123456", "transaction Request": { "transaction Type": "auth Capture Transaction", "amount": "45", "profile": { "customer Profile Id": "40338125", "payment Profile": { "payment Profile Id": "1000177237" } }, "line Items": { "line Item": { "item Id": "1", "name": "vase", "description": "Cannes logo", "quantity": "18", "unit Price": "45.00" } }, "processing Options": { "is Subsequent
Auth": "true" }, "subsequent Auth Information": { "original Network Trans Id": "123456789123456", "original Auth Amount": "45.00", "reason": "resubmission"
```